# Adding simpleContent using nusoap

Tags: php, xml, wsdl, nusoap, simpletype

My problem seems to be very simple, but I just can't find any solution.

I use nusoap for webservice, and I need to produce a structure like this (from php arrray):

```
<ns0:measurementUnitList>
       <ns0:measurementUnit type="type1">type1.value</ns0:measurementUnit>
       <ns0:measurementUnit type="type2">type1.value</ns0:measurementUnit>
</ns0:measurementUnitList>
```

The requred xsd looks like this:

```
<xsd:complexType name="measurementUnit">
        <xsd:simpleContent>
            <xsd:extension base="xsd:string">
                <xsd:attribute name="type" type="xsd:string" use="required" >                    
                </xsd:attribute>
            </xsd:extension>
        </xsd:simpleContent>
</xsd:complexType>
```

... and the problematical php array part looks like this:

```
[measurementUnitList] => Array(
     [measurementUnit] => Array
     (
        [0] => Array
        (
            [type] => type1
            [unit] => type1.value
        )

        [1] => Array
        (
            [type] => type2
            [unit] => type2.value
        )

     )

)
```

In this example, "type" attribute must be generated from the php array's "type" element, and the content should come from the same php array's "unit" element.

The problem is that anyhow I try to put "unit" into the element's content, the library generates a new "unit" element into the "measurementUnit" element with this content, like this:

```
<ns1:measurementUnitList>
    <ns1:measurementUnit type="type1">
         <ns1:unit>type1.value</ns1:unit>
    </ns1:measurementUnit>
    <ns1:measurementUnit type="type2">
         <ns1:unit>type2.value</ns1:unit>
    </ns1:measurementUnit>
</ns1:measurementUnitList>
```

So I just can't figure out, how I could just simply use the value without any additional tags.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
[measurementUnitList] => Array(
     [measurementUnit] => Array
     (
        [0] => Array
        (
            [type] => type1
            [!] => type1.value
        )

        [1] => Array
        (
            [type] => type2
            [!] => type2.value
        )

     )

)
```